# Error Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Alright, so I am working on a Time Report project just to get familiar with asp.net mvc5 and databases and all that jazz.

I can report a date, but I want to report several dates. In my controller, I did this for that :

```
            string d = form["date"];
            string[] dates = d.Split(' ');

            foreach (var date in dates)
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, out reportDate))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Felaktikt datum");
                }
```

It's pretty basic and straight forward each date is seperated by a space, and I add the dates to a string array and for each date in that array it will execute the code. I have that working good.

The first run it does with the first date everything works great, it reports that time but the second time in the loop I get the following error: **Nullable object must have a value.**

And it's at this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Projects.Count; i++)
        {
            reportProjects[i] = new TimeReportProject
            {
                Description = Projects[i].Description,
                FK_ProjectID = Projects[i].ProjectId,
                FK_TimeReportID = ReportId.Value,
                Hours = Projects[i].Hours.Value,
                HourRate = db.GetProjectHourRate(Projects[i].ProjectId, Date, Projects[i].Hours.Value),
                TimeReportProjectID = Guid.NewGuid()
            };
        }
```

It's at `Hours = Projects[i].Hours.Value,` to be exact, that line get's null the second time it goes around.

So in order to fix that I just did a pretty basic nullcheck and now that section looks like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Projects.Count; i++)
            {
                var hours = Projects[i].Hours;
                if (hours != null)
                    reportProjects[i] = new TimeReportProject
                    {
                        Description = Projects[i].Description,
                        FK_ProjectID = Projects[i].ProjectId,
                        FK_TimeReportID = ReportId.Value,
                       *Hours = hours.Value,
                        HourRate = db.GetProjectHourRate(Projects[i].ProjectId, Date, hours.Value),
                        TimeReportProjectID = Guid.NewGuid()
                    };
            }
```

And that works, how ever after it continues to run I get stuck at the following code:

```
        public void AddToTimeReportProjects(TimeReportProject timeReportProject)
    {
        base.AddObject("TimeReportProjects", timeReportProject);
    }
```

this is the error:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

First of I do not understand why it doesn't work when it runs the second loop to add the second date to the report, the first works great I've been debugging and it does everything the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, calling `Value` on a `Nullable<T>` actually says you know it has a value, or else it throws an exception if the value is found to be `null`. You should always check `HasValue` before you call `Value`.

Instead of all that, you can use `Projects[i].Hours.GetValueOrDefault()` which will yield `0` for integers when `Hours` is `null`.

I guess in your second code sample, `timeReportProject` is `null`, which is not allowed apparently.

Comment: But that seems not to be desired, the object should not be initialized even if that causes the next exception. So i'm not sure if OP wants to avoid the second exception by assigning default values. Maybe he just wants to create a smaller array.

Comment: Indeed, but OP didn't ask what to do, he already knows that. But he asked why it happened.

Comment: When the first loop is ran as in the first date etc 2015-08-11 than hours isn't null, but when all that is done and that date been reported and it's going to do it a second time 2015-08-12 etc hours will get null, so I did add the null check. And it does catch that and it runs that again and the next time hours is back to 8.

Comment: But if I were to use Projects[i].Hours.GetValueOrDefault() the second date I would end up getting 0 hours instead of the 8 I am getting the first day.

Comment: Then there is a bug in retrieving your data. The current code isn't enough to tell anything about it, but it does tell why you end up with those results. Where do you save that data?

Comment: If everything is ok, and it posts like it should it's saved in a DB. I find it really strange for the second date that it gets hours null. Because when debugging it does everything the same, and all the variable holds the right values like the first time.